# Exporting unique values of classified image as CSV

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to export a CSV that contains all of the classified integer values of of an image in Google Earth Engine using the Python API. I have this working in JavaScript, but I'm a little lost while translating it.

My JavaScript code is essentially:

```
var reduction_evt = lf_evt_20.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: eight_state, 
  maxPixels: 1e12
});

var values_evt = ee.Dictionary(reduction_evt.get(lf_evt_20.bandNames().get(0)))
  .keys()
  .map(ee.Number.parse);

var evt_fc_2020 = ee.FeatureCollection(values
                                       .map(function(element){
                                       return ee.Feature(null, {prop:element})}));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: evt_fc_2020,
  description: 'lf_evt_2020_reclass',
  folder: 'EE_exports',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
})
```

While my python (in a jupyter notebook) is:

```
reduction = lf_evt_20.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
                                   geometry=eight_state,
                                   scale=30,
                                   maxPixels=1e12)

values_evt = ee.Dictionary(reduction.get(lf_evt_20.bandNames().get(0))).keys()
values_evt_parsed = ee.Number.parse(values_evt)

## apply the missing ee.Number.parse function
values_evt = map(ee.Number.parse, values_evt)
```

But this last line yields:

> TypeError: 'List' object is not iterable

I'm struggling getting this to translate to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different path. Instead of parsing the numbers and using the earthengine export tools, I used list.getinfo() to return a client-side variable and exported as usual using a pandas dataframe. This code ran:

```
#extract python list from ee.list type
evt_list_client = values_evt.getInfo()

#convert list to pandas dataframe and convert type to int
lf_classes_df = pd.DataFrame({'class':evt_list_client})
lf_classes_df = lf_classes_df.astype(int)


#### Export dataframe as csv using direct path
lf_classes_df.to_csv(r'C:/Users/username/landfire_classes_8state.csv')
```